# Cut out of a block of multiple columns of text

Tags: multicol, shapepar

Is it possible to cut out a very specific shape of a block of multiple columns of text? Cut out of a block of text in one column is simple enough with the help of Xfig, Transfig and Shapepar, as per the MWE, but I just can't get it to work with multiple columns. Commands like

```
\kurupar{%
\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum*[1-5]
\end{multicols}%
}
```

doesn't compile, giving error messages `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`, `\begin{document} ended by \end{multicols}`, and `Missing } inserted`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,latin]{article}

\usepackage{babel,lipsum,microtype,shapepar,multicol}

%The shape I'm after, generated with the help of Xfig and Transfig
\def\kurupar#1{\shapepar{\kurushape}#1\par}
\def\kurushape{%
{25.0504}%
{0.0504032}b{0.0504032}\\%
{0.0504032}t{0.0504032}{50}\\%
{12.9032}t{0.0504032}{12.8024}st{12.8528}{25.9577}st{38.8105}{11.2399}\\%
{12.9032}t{0.0504032}{11.2399}t{12.8528}{24.3952}t{38.8105}{11.2399}\\%
{13.0544}t{0.0504032}{10.3327}t{13.7601}{22.5806}t{39.7177}{10.3327}\\%
{13.3065}t{0.0504032}{9.4254}t{14.6673}{20.7661}t{40.625}{9.4254}\\%
{13.6593}t{0.0504032}{8.61895}t{15.4738}{19.1532}t{41.4315}{8.61895}\\%
{14.1129}t{0.0504032}{7.8125}t{16.2802}{17.5403}t{42.2379}{7.8125}\\%
{14.7177}t{0.0504032}{7.10685}t{16.9859}{16.129}t{42.9436}{7.10685}\\%
{15.373}t{0.0504032}{6.50202}t{17.5907}{14.9194}t{43.5484}{6.50202}\\%
{16.129}t{0.0504032}{5.94758}t{18.1452}{13.8105}t{44.1028}{5.94758}\\%
{16.9355}t{0.0504032}{5.54435}t{18.5484}{13.004}t{44.5061}{5.54435}\\%
{17.7923}t{0.0504032}{5.24194}t{18.8508}{12.3992}t{44.8085}{5.24194}\\%
{18.6996}t{0.0504032}{5.04032}t{19.0524}{11.996}t{45.0101}{5.04032}\\%
{29.5363}t{0.0504032}{4.98992}t{19.1028}{11.8952}t{45.0605}{4.98992}\\%
{30.4435}t{0.0504032}{5.04032}t{19.0524}{11.996}t{45.0101}{5.04032}\\%
{31.3508}t{0.0504032}{5.24194}t{18.8508}{12.3992}t{44.8085}{5.24194}\\%
{32.2077}t{0.0504032}{5.54435}t{18.5484}{13.004}t{44.5061}{5.54435}\\%
{33.0141}t{0.0504032}{5.94758}t{18.1452}{13.8105}t{44.1028}{5.94758}\\%
{33.7702}t{0.0504032}{6.50202}t{17.5907}{14.9194}t{43.5484}{6.50202}\\%
{34.123}t{0.0504032}{6.8277}t{17.265}{8.03738}st{25.3024}{7.53334}t{43.2227}{6.8277}\\%
{34.1734}t{0.0504032}{6.87422}t{17.2185}{7.07584}t{26.3105}{6.57181}t{43.1762}{6.87423}\\%
{34.375}t{0.0504032}{7.06033}t{17.0324}{6.25388}t{27.3185}{5.74984}t{42.9901}{7.06033}\\%
{34.4254}t{0.0504032}{7.10685}t{16.9859}{6.17079}t{27.4482}{5.66676}t{42.9436}{7.10685}\\%
{34.7278}t{0.0504032}{7.45968}t{16.6331}{5.74597}t{28.2258}{5.24194}t{42.5907}{7.45968}\\%
{35.0302}t{0.0504032}{7.8125}t{16.2802}{5.49395}t{28.8306}{4.98992}t{42.2379}{7.8125}\\%
{35.1815}t{0.0504032}{8.08132}t{16.0114}{5.46035}t{29.1331}{4.95632}t{41.9691}{8.08132}\\%
{35.4839}t{0.0504032}{8.61895}t{15.4738}{5.5581}t{29.5729}{5.05407}t{41.4315}{8.61895}\\%
{35.7359}t{0.0504032}{9.19499}t{14.8978}{5.76757}t{29.9395}{5.26354}t{40.8554}{9.19499}\\%
{35.8367}t{0.0504032}{9.4254}t{14.6673}{5.88998}t{30.0475}{5.38594}t{40.625}{9.4254}\\%
{36.0887}t{0.0504032}{10.3327}t{13.7601}{6.52722}t{30.3175}{6.02319}t{39.7177}{10.3327}\\%
{36.2399}t{0.0504032}{11.2399}t{12.8528}{7.27247}t{30.4796}{6.76843}t{38.8105}{11.2399}\\%
{36.2399}t{0.0504032}{11.2399}jt{11.2903}{8.83496}t{30.4796}{6.76843}jt{37.248}{12.8024}\\%
{36.4415}t{0.0504032}{19.8589}t{30.6956}{19.3548}\\%
{37.248}t{0.0504032}{19.2036}t{31.3508}{18.6996}\\%
{38.1048}t{0.0504032}{18.6996}t{31.8548}{18.1956}\\%
{39.0121}t{0.0504032}{18.2964}t{32.2581}{17.7923}\\%
{39.9698}t{0.0504032}{18.0444}t{32.5101}{17.5403}\\%
{40.9778}t{0.0504032}{17.8931}t{32.6613}{17.3891}\\%
{41.9859}t{0.0504032}{17.8931}t{32.6613}{17.3891}\\%
{42.994}t{0.0504032}{18.0444}t{32.5101}{17.5403}\\%
{43.9516}t{0.0504032}{18.2964}t{32.2581}{17.7923}\\%
{44.8589}t{0.0504032}{18.6996}t{31.8548}{18.1956}\\%
{45.7157}t{0.0504032}{19.2036}t{31.3508}{18.6996}\\%
{46.5222}t{0.0504032}{19.8589}t{30.6956}{19.3548}\\%
{47.2278}t{0.0504032}{20.6149}t{29.9395}{20.1109}\\%
{47.7823}t{0.0504032}{21.4214}t{29.1331}{20.9173}\\%
{48.2359}t{0.0504032}{22.3286}t{28.2258}{21.8246}\\%
{48.5887}t{0.0504032}{23.2359}t{27.3185}{22.7319}\\%
{48.7903}t{0.0504032}{24.244}t{26.3105}{23.7399}\\%
{48.8407}t{0.0504032}{25.252}jt{25.3024}{24.748}\\%
{50.8065}t{0.0504032}{25.252}st{25.3024}{24.748}\\%
{50.8569}t{0.0504032}{24.244}t{26.3105}{23.7399}\\%
{51.0585}t{0.0504032}{23.2359}t{27.3185}{22.7319}\\%
{51.4113}t{0.0504032}{22.3286}t{28.2258}{21.8246}\\%
{51.8649}t{0.0504032}{21.4214}t{29.1331}{20.9173}\\%
{52.4194}t{0.0504032}{20.6149}t{29.9395}{20.1109}\\%
{53.125}t{0.0504032}{19.8589}t{30.6956}{19.3548}\\%
{53.9315}t{0.0504032}{19.2036}t{31.3508}{18.6996}\\%
{54.7883}t{0.0504032}{18.6996}t{31.8548}{18.1956}\\%
{55.6956}t{0.0504032}{18.2964}t{32.2581}{17.7923}\\%
{56.6532}t{0.0504032}{18.0444}t{32.5101}{17.5403}\\%
{57.6613}t{0.0504032}{17.8931}t{32.6613}{17.3891}\\%
{58.6694}t{0.0504032}{17.8931}t{32.6613}{17.3891}\\%
{59.6774}t{0.0504032}{18.0444}t{32.5101}{17.5403}\\%
{60.6351}t{0.0504032}{18.2964}t{32.2581}{17.7923}\\%
{61.5423}t{0.0504032}{18.6996}t{31.8548}{18.1956}\\%
{62.3992}t{0.0504032}{19.2036}t{31.3508}{18.6996}\\%
{63.2056}t{0.0504032}{19.8589}t{30.6956}{19.3548}\\%
{63.9113}t{0.0504032}{20.6149}t{29.9395}{20.1109}\\%
{64.4657}t{0.0504032}{21.4214}t{29.1331}{20.9173}\\%
{64.9194}t{0.0504032}{22.3286}t{28.2258}{21.8246}\\%
{65.2722}t{0.0504032}{23.2359}t{27.3185}{22.7319}\\%
{65.4738}t{0.0504032}{24.244}t{26.3105}{23.7399}\\%
{65.5242}t{0.0504032}{25.252}jt{25.3024}{24.748}\\%
{70.7661}t{0.0504032}{50}\\%
{70.7661}e{50.0504}%
}

\begin{document}
\kurupar{\lipsum*[1-5]}

\clearpage

\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Mockup of the effect I'm after:

[image: Mockup of the effect I'm after]